# Reading from a .txt file and making conditions from it

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
client = input("What is your Client ID. CaSe SeNsItIvE")
file = open("clientIntensity.txt" , "r")
found = False
for line in file:
    if (client) in line:
      found = True
```

I want to make the program so that if they enter a correct Client ID, it will search for the ID in the given .txt file. When found, it will print the 6-14 characters(They are either 'High' or 'Moderate'). It will then print something based on the 6-14 characters. I have made that much so far... Thanks!
(Python 3.4.2)

Comment: And what is the problem here?

Comment: What "6-14 characters"?

Comment: if the .txt file contains the id they enter, it will print the 6-14 characters of that line.

Comment: I don't know how to print something based on the 6-14 characters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to print the 6th to 14th characters of the line containing the client ID, you can do this:

```
client = input("What is your Client ID. CaSe SeNsItIvE")
file = open("clientIntensity.txt" , "r")
for line in file:
    if client in line:
        print(line[5:13])
        break
```

(You use 5 and 13 to get the 6th-14th characters because the first character is numbered zero)

Edit. If you want to print something based on the content of the 6th-14th characters you can do it like this:

```
def get_security(filename, client_id):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if client_id in line:
                return line[5:13]

client = input("What is your Client ID. CaSe SeNsItIvE")
security = get_security('clientIntensity.txt', client)
if security is None:
    print ("Client ID not found")
elif security.startswith('High'):
    print('Good')
elif security == 'Moderate':
    print('Bad')
else:
    print('There has been an error')
```

Comment: I want to print something based on the characters for example- if [6:14] = High, print "well done"

Comment: Give us a clue... give an example input and expected output in the question.

Comment: if the 6-14 characters are 'High', print'Good'

Comment: if the 6-14 characters are 'moderate' print'bad'

Comment: Thank you! Do i need to change anything?